# how to open a accordion when click a span which out side of heading

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

i cant open a accordion from out side of heading

in my case there have a **div** with id accordion

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3 style="width:400px;">Product Description</h3>
    <div>Content Panel 1</div>
    <h3 style="width:400px;">Product Specification</h3>
    <div>Content Panel 2</div>

    <h3 style="width:400px;">Shiping+Return Polices</h3>
    <div>Content Panel 3</div>
    <h3 style="width:400px;" id="ac">Product Reviews</h3>
    <div id="newdivratting">

    </div>
    <h3 style="width:400px;">QuestionAnswer</h3>
    <div id="QuestionAnswer">
    </div>
    <h3 style="width:400px;">Close All</h3>
    <div>Closed.</div>
</div>
```

and a **span** tag which is outside of accordion

```
<span style="padding:10px;" class="span-click" id="reviewread">Click me</span>
```

and i am trying to  when click this **span** then open 4th accordion where heading is **Product Reviews**

my jquery code is

```
   $("#reviewread").click(function () {
            $("accordion>#ac").accordion("activate", true);
           // $('html,body').animate({
              //  scrollTop: $("#newdivratting").offset().top
           // },
             //   'slow');
        });
```

how can i fixed it please help.

Comment: `$(el).trigger('click')` from the element you want to open the accordion and el here being the accordion header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trigger the click at the target element:

```js
$("#accordion").accordion();
$("#reviewread").click(function(e) {
  $("#ac").trigger("click");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<span style="padding:10px;" class="span-click" id="reviewread">Click me</span>
<div id="accordion">
  <h3 style="width:400px;">Product Description</h3>
  <div>Content Panel 1</div>
  <h3 style="width:400px;">Product Specification</h3>
  <div>Content Panel 2</div>

  <h3 style="width:400px;">Shiping+Return Polices</h3>
  <div>Content Panel 3</div>
  <h3 style="width:400px;" id="ac">Product Reviews</h3>
  <div id="newdivratting">

  </div>
  <h3 style="width:400px;">QuestionAnswer</h3>
  <div id="QuestionAnswer">
  </div>
  <h3 style="width:400px;">Close All</h3>
  <div>Closed.</div>
</div>
```